# Raspberry Pi Training model using Google Coral

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, google-coral

Is it possible to train EfficientDet lite model using TPU Google Coral accelerator on Raspberry Pi 4 (64 bit os bullseye)?

Comment: afaics, that thing is for inference, not training

Comment: You may want to look into Transfer Learning on device:

https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#transfer-learning

which is less demanding than a “full” model training from scratch.